# boolean function for loop mql4

Tags: for-loop, mql4

I would like to write a reiterated if condition

```
if (BOX_H1(1) && BOX_H1(2) && BOX_H1(3) && BOX_H1(4) && BOX_H1(5) && BOX_H1(6) && BOX_H1(7) && BOX_H1(8);)
```

In a for loop form, something like this:

```
if (
for (int x=1;x<=7; x++)
          {
               (BOX_H1(x));

          })
```

where `BOX_H1(1)` si a boolean functions that takes int (shift parameter), but this code doesen't works.

Anyone knows how can i write it out?

EDIT:
My code is in this form:

`bool Buy_H1 =0, ...`

...

`if(Buy_H1) {if(...)}`

...

```
void Entry() 
{
Buy_H1 =BOX_H1(1) && BOX_H1(2) && BOX_H1(3) && BOX_H1(4) && 
        BOX_H1(5) && BOX_H1(6) && BOX_H1(7) && BOX_H1(8) ;
}
```

If, instead of the last code, I substitute

```
void Entry() 
{
bool Buy_H1(const int parameter){
for(int i=1; i<=parameter; i++){
  if(!BOX_H1(i))
     return false; }
return true; }
}
```

I reach  `'Buy_H1' - function can be declared only in the global scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool booleanFunction( const int parameter ){
     for( int i = 1; i <= parameter; i++ ){
          if ( !BOX_H1( i ) )
               return false;
     }
     return true;
}


void OnStart(){
     ...
     if (  booleanFunction( 8 ) ){
           Print( "OK" );
     }                                   //edited, your code instead of this
     ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesen't works.
Say "unexpected token" for "boolean function" and "parameter" 
Below shows "'return' - 'void' function returns a value"

Comment: you missed ")" somewhere or some other sign

Comment: if you copied the last line (it is just an example for you) - then i edited

Comment: reach  ` 'Buy_H1' - function can be declared only in the global scope`
I edited in my first answare the entire code

Comment: you have buyh1() function inside entry() function which is not correct.

Comment: `void entry(){ bool buyH1 = booleanfunction(8); if(buyH1){...}}` the way it should work

Comment: I only don't understand why 8 in booleanfunction

Comment: booleanfunction(param) - 8 is param

Comment: ok, that way works. Last question, why you wrote 

`if(!BOX_H1(i))
return false;`

instead of 

`if(BOX_H1(i))
return true;`

the two codes aren't equal?

Comment: you need to check all 8 (or how many) cases. if any of them is false - whole statement is false